# Building a custom blogging system - design suggestions

Tags: blogs

I am going to build a very simple blogging system in PHP. It should be SEO optimized.

I want to ask you some suggestions to get it right the first time.

I have also some specific questions:
1) Do you think embedding the timestamp in the URL ( /2011/03/25/how-to-build-a-blog) has got any real benefit?
2) Where is the best place to insert social widgets (facebook like button and tweet button).
3) Is there any reliable way to notify your new post automatically to major services (Digg, Google, Technorati)?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of an opinion question than a hard answer question, but since nobody has answered in the last few months, I'll share my opinions. Hope they help.

1) I like knowing the dates of posts, so in my blog I have the date as part of the URL, but if you're feeling minimalist, I don't think it's a big deal to take it out.

2) I like the social widgets to be at the end of every post. That way, after I'm done reading, I can decide if I want to share.

3) There are plugins to let you automatically tweet and post to facebook. You can also publish your blog as an RSS and I'm sure there are services that will follow your RSS and auto submit.